# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method & RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, errors, when fetching data from Firestore

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I was trying to fetch data from the `Firestore` and show it in a `RecyclerView`. But, I am getting the following errors.
I do not have much experience in coding, but I tried to add `RecyclerView` and `fragments` in my project.

I am using `Kotlin` as language.

I have been trying to figure out what went wrong and for a solution for the last three days but now I think I must seek help from experts like you.

Following is the error I get in the `Logcat`

```
16273-16273/com.example.quiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.quiz, PID: 16273
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quiz/com.example.quiz.ui.activities.DashboardActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in com.example.quiz:layout/activity_dashboard: Binary XML file line #32 in com.example.quiz:layout/activity_dashboard: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in com.example.quiz:layout/activity_dashboard: Binary XML file line #32 in com.example.quiz:layout/activity_dashboard: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in com.example.quiz:layout/activity_dashboard: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.quiz.ui.fragments.DashboardFragment.onCreateView(DashboardFragment.kt:28)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
2021-05-27 07:25:09.097 16273-16273/com.example.quiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.quiz.ui.activities.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.kt:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
2021-05-27 07:25:09.166 16273-16273/com.example.quiz I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16273 SIG: 9
```

`Quiz.kt` file

```
package com.example.quiz.models

import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Quiz(
    val user_id: String = "",
    var quiz_id: String = "",
    val quiz_name: String = "",
    val num_participants: String = "",
    val num_questions: String = "",
    val duration: String = ""

) : Parcelable
```

`DashboardActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.quiz.ui.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import com.example.quiz.R

class DashboardActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)
        
        supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this@DashboardActivity,
                R.drawable.app_gradient_color_background
            )
        )

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_quizzes,
                R.id.navigation_dashboard
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        doubleBackToExit()
    }
}
```

`DashboardItemListAdapter.kt`

```
package com.example.quiz.ui.adapters

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.quiz.R
import com.example.quiz.models.Quiz
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_list_layout.view.*


open class DashboardItemsListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var list: ArrayList<Quiz>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


    private var onClickListener: OnClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_dashboard_layout,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = list[position]

        if (holder is MyViewHolder) {

            holder.itemView.tv_quiz_name.text = model.quiz_name
            holder.itemView.tv_participants.text = model.num_participants
            holder.itemView.tv_questions.text = model.num_questions
            holder.itemView.tv_duration.text = model.duration

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                if (onClickListener != null) {
                    onClickListener!!.onClick(position, model)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }


    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }


    interface OnClickListener {

        fun onClick(position: Int, product: Quiz)
    }


    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

`QuizListAdapter.kt`

```
package com.example.quiz.ui.adapters

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.quiz.R
import com.example.quiz.models.Quiz
//import com.example.Quiz.utils.GlideLoader
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_list_layout.view.*

open class QuizListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val list: ArrayList<Quiz>,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_list_layout,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val model = list[position]

        if (holder is MyViewHolder) {

            holder.itemView.tv_quiz_name.text = model.quiz_name
            holder.itemView.tv_participants.text = model.num_participants
            holder.itemView.tv_questions.text = model.num_questions
            holder.itemView.tv_duration.text = model.duration

        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return list.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

`DashboardFragment.kt`

```
package com.example.quiz.ui.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.example.quiz.R
import com.example.quiz.firestore.FirestoreClass
import com.example.quiz.models.Quiz
import com.example.quiz.ui.adapters.DashboardItemsListAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_dashboard.*

class DashboardFragment : BaseFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        getDashboardItemsList()
    }

    private fun getDashboardItemsList() {
        showProgressDialog("please_wait")

        FirestoreClass().getDashboardItemsList(this@DashboardFragment)
    }

    fun successDashboardItemsList(dashboardItemsList: ArrayList<Quiz>) {

        hideProgressDialog()

        for (i in dashboardItemsList) {
            Log.i("Item Title", i.quiz_name)
        }

        if (dashboardItemsList.size > 0) {

            rv_dashboard_items.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tv_no_dashboard_items_found.visibility = View.GONE

            rv_dashboard_items.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 1)
            rv_dashboard_items.setHasFixedSize(true)

            val adapter = DashboardItemsListAdapter(requireActivity(), dashboardItemsList)
            rv_dashboard_items.adapter = adapter

        } else {
            rv_dashboard_items.visibility = View.GONE
            tv_no_dashboard_items_found.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code my app crashes after logging in entering the username and password, but when I remove the `rv_dashboard_items.adapter = adapter` at least the app does not crashes. However, it does not show any data from the `Firestore` at all.

I get the following errors when I run the app without `rv_dashboard_items.adapter = adapter`

The message in the following snippet was in red colour.

```
E/DashboardFragment: [DocumentSnapshot{key=quizzes/C8STnkYwp3cYWMxm1Y0xQWERTZq1, metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false}, doc=Document{key=quizzes/C8STnkYwp3cYWMxm1Y0xQWERTZq1, version=SnapshotVersion(seconds=1621955183, nanos=678854000), type=FOUND_DOCUMENT, documentState=SYNCED, value=ObjectValue{internalValue=# com.google.firestore.v1.Value@1abc2d14
integer_value: 0
map_value {
  fields {
    key: "quiz_id"
    value {
      integer_value: 0
      string_value: "C8STnkYwp3cYWMxm1Y0xQWERTZq1"
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "num_questions"
    value {
      integer_value: 0
      string_value: "10"
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "quiz_name"
    value {
      integer_value: 0
      string_value: "Easy Quiz"
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "duration"
    value {
      integer_value: 0
      string_value: "10"
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "num_participants"
    value {
      integer_value: 0
      string_value: "5"
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "user_id"
    value {
      integer_value: 0
      string_value: "C8STnkYwp3cYWMxm1Y0xQWERTZq1"
    }
  }
}}}}]
```

Also this line

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

`QuizFragment.kt`

```
package com.example.quiz.ui.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.quiz.R
import com.example.quiz.firestore.FirestoreClass
import com.example.quiz.models.Quiz
import com.example.quiz.ui.adapters.QuizListAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_quiz.*

class QuizFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var mRootView: View


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz, container, false)
        return mRootView
    }

    fun successQuizListFromFireStore(quizList: ArrayList<Quiz>) {

        hideProgressDialog()

        if (quizList.size > 0) {
            rvQuizzesFrag.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tv_no_products_found.visibility = View.GONE

            rvQuizzesFrag.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            rvQuizzesFrag.setHasFixedSize(true)
            val adapterQuizzes = QuizListAdapter(requireActivity(), quizList)
            rvQuizzesFrag.adapter = adapterQuizzes

        } else {
            rvQuizzesFrag.visibility = View.GONE
            tv_no_products_found.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }


    private fun getQuizListFromFireStore() {

        showProgressDialog("Please_wait")
        FirestoreClass().getQuizList(this)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        getQuizListFromFireStore()
    }
}
```

`activity_dashboard.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_color_background"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment_dashboard.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.DashboardFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_dashboard_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_dashboard_items_found"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="no_dashboard_item_found"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment_quiz.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.QuizFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvQuizzesFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_products_found"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="NO QUIZZES TODAY"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`FirestoreClass.kt`

`Import` part of the code is deleted from the question as I exceed the character limit in the question.

```
package com.example.quiz.firestore


class FirestoreClass {

    private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    fun getDashboardItemsList(fragment: DashboardFragment) {
       
        mFireStore.collection("quizzes")
            .get() 
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                Log.e(fragment.javaClass.simpleName, document.documents.toString())

                val quizList: ArrayList<Quiz> = ArrayList()

               
                for (i in document.documents) {

                    val qz = i.toObject(Quiz::class.java)!!
                    qz.quiz_id = i.id
                    quizList.add(qz)
                }

                fragment.successDashboardItemsList(quizList)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
              
                fragment.hideProgressDialog()
                Log.e(fragment.javaClass.simpleName, "Error while getting dashboard items list.", e)
            }
    }


    fun getCurrentUserID(): String {
        // An Instance of currentUser using FirebaseAuth
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        var currentUserID = ""
        if (currentUser != null) {
            currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        }

        return currentUserID
    }


    fun uploadProductDetails(activity: AddProductActivity, productInfo: Quiz) {

        mFireStore.collection("quizzes")
            .document()
          
            .set(productInfo, SetOptions.merge())
            .addOnSuccessListener {

              
                activity.productUploadSuccess()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->

                activity.hideProgressDialog()

                Log.e(
                    activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                    "Error while uploading the product details.",
                    e
                )
            }
    }

    fun getUserDetails(activity: Activity) {

        mFireStore.collection("users")
         
            .document(getCurrentUserID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                Log.i(activity.javaClass.simpleName, document.toString())

                val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!

                val sharedPreferences =
                    activity.getSharedPreferences(
                        Constants.MYAPP_PREFERENCES,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE
                    )

                val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                editor.putString(
                    Constants.LOGGED_IN_USERNAME,
                    "${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}"
                )
                editor.apply()

                when (activity) {
                    is LoginActivity -> {
                      
                        activity.userLoggedInSuccess(user)
                    }

                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
               
                when (activity) {
                    is LoginActivity -> {
                        activity.hideProgressDialog()
                    }
                }

                Log.e(
                    activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                    "Error while getting user details.",
                    e
                )
            }
    }


    fun getQuizList(fragment: Fragment) {
      
        mFireStore.collection("quizzes")
            .whereEqualTo("user_id", getCurrentUserID())
            .get() 
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                Log.e("Products List", document.documents.toString())

                val productsList: ArrayList<Quiz> = ArrayList()

                for (i in document.documents) {

                    val product = i.toObject(Quiz::class.java)
                    product!!.quiz_id = i.id

                    productsList.add(product)
                }

                when (fragment) {
                    is QuizFragment -> {
                        fragment.successQuizListFromFireStore(productsList)
                    }
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
               
                when (fragment) {
                    is QuizFragment -> {
                        fragment.hideProgressDialog()
                    }
                }

                Log.e("Get Product List", "Error while getting product list.", e)
            }
    }


    fun getAllQuizList(activity: Activity) {
       
        mFireStore.collection("quizzes")
            .get() 
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                Log.e("Products List", document.documents.toString())

                val productsList: ArrayList<Quiz> = ArrayList()

                for (i in document.documents) {

                    val product = i.toObject(Quiz::class.java)
                    product!!.quiz_id = i.id

                    productsList.add(product)
                }

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e("Get Product List", "Error while getting all product list.", e)
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your code, I think the reason for this is: there may be some minor problems with the use of your `recycleView`.

In your code, you seem to use two `recycleView` in the same place of `xml`, one is the `recycleView` with no data, and the other is the `recycleView` after getting the data asynchronously. And then control the display and hiding of recycleView in the function of getting data?

However, if you do not initialize the recyclerview immediately after attaching it to the Fragment, you may see `No adapter attached; skipping layout`.

Solution: Just set a `recycleView`, and set an empty data to it in the initialization function of Fragment/activity. `DashboardItemsListAdapter(requireActivity(), listOf<Quiz>())`

Part of the code:

```kotlin
private lateinit var adapter: DashboardItemsListAdapter

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    adapter = DashboardItemsListAdapter(requestActivity(), arrayListOf<Quiz>())
}

fun successDashboardItemsList(dashboardItemsList: ArrayList<Quiz>) {
    adapter.list = dashboardItemsList
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

I just provide one of my thoughts here. You cannot set a new adapter every time you call `successDashboardItemsList()`. Before calling `successDashboardItemsList()`, your adapter should be initialized (there may be no data) . Every time `successDashboardItemsList()` is called,
Re-assign the value of the list field of the Adapter object. And call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` of the Adapter object, so that the problem can be solved.

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.example.quiz.R
import com.example.quiz.firestore.FirestoreClass
import com.example.quiz.models.Quiz
import com.example.quiz.ui.adapters.DashboardItemsListAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_dashboard.*

class DashboardFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var adapter: DashboardItemsListAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
    }



    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_dashboard_items)
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_dashboard_items_found)
        adapter = DashboardItemsListAdapter(requireActivity(), arrayListOf<Quiz>())
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 1)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        getDashboardItemsList()
    }

    private fun getDashboardItemsList() {
        showProgressDialog("please_wait")

        FirestoreClass().getDashboardItemsList(this@DashboardFragment)
    }

    fun successDashboardItemsList(dashboardItemsList: ArrayList<Quiz>) {

        hideProgressDialog()

        for (i in dashboardItemsList) {
            Log.i("Item Title", i.quiz_name)
        }

        if (dashboardItemsList.size > 0) {

            recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            textView.visibility = View.GONE

            adapter.list = dashboardItemsList
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
            textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

`DashboardItemListAdapter.kt`

change into:

```kotlin
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         return MyViewHolder(
             LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                 R.layout.item_list_layout,
                 parent,
                 false
             )
         )
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried to add the piece of code that you provided but I couldn't fix the errors shown in the editor. I have added some more codes in my first post. Could you please check it now?

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you are still confused, it is convenient to provide the activity/fragment where the recycleView is located?

Comment: I went through your updated response but as a beginner, I am not able to fix it. I have updated my question with complete code (of those files which I think could cause the errors) instead of bit and pieces.  Could you take a look now?

Comment: I updated the code in DashboardFragment, you can try to solve the problem. :)

Comment: I tried your code and I replaced `listOf<Quiz>()` with `ArrayList<Quiz>` as it showed 'Type mismatch'.  In the Logcat there are many lines of errors and two of them are pointing at `rv_dashboard_items.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 1)` in `DashboardFragment` and `setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)` in `DashboardActivity.kt`. Logcat in my question is updated with new error.

Comment: Error is same and I have updated the `Logcat`. `DashboardFragment.kt:28` refers to `rv_dashboard_items.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 1)` in `DashboardFragment.kt` , `DashboardActivity.kt:15` refers to  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)` in `DashboardActivity.kt` and `Binary XML file line #32` refers to `app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232930/discussion-between-codist-and-future-deep-gone).

Answer (score 1):

In your `DashboardItemsListAdapter` you are inflating `item_dashboard_layout` but you're importing synthetic bindings for `fragment_dashboard`.

The inflated layout likely does not contain views that would be required by the `fragment_dashboard` binding, hence the binding returns nulls.

Make sure you're using the same layout for both inflating and view binding.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the issue that you just found and provide the code that I should use? As a beginner, I don't know how to do what you just said.